# Changing Background color of Picker View

Tags: ios, uipickerview

How can i change the Color of my Picker view depending on the background color of the TextField? e.g i have 2 text fields, The one is red and the other one is blue, If i clicked the red one the picker background is red also, And if i click the blue one the picker background will be blue also? im using this code for the text field to show the picker view.

```
    int tag = [(UITextField*)sender tag];
self.myPicker.hidden = NO;
selectedTable = tag;
[sender resignFirstResponder];
float yy = 10;
switch (tag) {
    case 0: yy = self.txtTgfeet.frame.origin.y + self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
        break;
    case 1: yy = self.txtTginches.frame.origin.y + self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
        break;
    case 2: yy = self.txtTgfraction.frame.origin.y + self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
        break;
    case 3: yy = self.txtBgfeet.frame.origin.y - self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
        break;
    case 4: yy = self.txtBginches.frame.origin.y - self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
        break;
    case 5: yy = self.txtBgfraction.frame.origin.y - self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
        break;
    case 6: yy = self.txtGravity.frame.origin.y - self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
        break;
    case 7: yy = self.txtBsw.frame.origin.y - self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
        break;
    case 8: yy = self.txtTemp.frame.origin.y - self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
        break;


    default:
        break;
}
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  `self.picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` `UITextFieldDelegate` method and change color using by using tag property.

```
if(textField.tag == 1){
     self.picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else if(textField.tag == 2){
  self.picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else{

 //use default value
```

}

Edit:

```
switch (tag) {
    case 0: yy = self.txtTgfeet.frame.origin.y + self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
            self.picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        break;
    case 1: yy = self.txtTginches.frame.origin.y + self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
            self.picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor bluecolor];
        break;
    case 2: yy = self.txtTgfraction.frame.origin.y + self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
            self.picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        break;
    case 3: yy = self.txtBgfeet.frame.origin.y - self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
        break;
    case 4: yy = self.txtBginches.frame.origin.y - self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
        break;
    case 5: yy = self.txtBgfraction.frame.origin.y - self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
        break;
    case 6: yy = self.txtGravity.frame.origin.y - self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
        break;
    case 7: yy = self.txtBsw.frame.origin.y - self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
        break;
    case 8: yy = self.txtTemp.frame.origin.y - self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
        break;


    default:
        break;
}
```

add different background colour for each case

Comment: u can assign different tags to each textfield and check for the tag and assign different color. if you want to give same color the use OR condition to check the tag number and assign color

Comment: i tried this, 


`if(_txtfield1){
        self.myPicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
if(_txtfield2){
        self.myPicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
if(_txtfield3){
        self.myPicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
if(_txtfield4){
        self.myPicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    `

i cant make it work, if what is the last color that is the color of all picker

Comment: use tag property of each textfield to check

Comment: can you provide a sample according to my textfields tags on the top?

Comment: all of that field has different colors

Comment: when i click a UITextField the Picker will show, i want the Text field assigned with colors and the picker background color will be the color of which textfield i clicked